# Perform different segues using switchCase

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `UIPickerView` with 5 different objects and also a button. When I push the button, I want to go to the next ViewController.

For example: when I select `Options` in the `UIPickerView` and push the button, I want to go to the OptionsViewController ... I tried it with a switchCase but it didn't work for me. Inside the switchCase, I put:

```
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToOptions" sender:nil];
```

My question is now: how do I have to connect the viewcontrollers and how do I call this viewcontroller switch?

The complete switchCase is:

```
  switch (rowSelected) {
            case Start_Game:
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToGame" sender:sender];
                break;
            case Scores:
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToScores" sender:sender];
                break;
            case How_To_Play:
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToHTP" sender:sender];
                break;
            case Options:
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToOptions" sender:sender];
                break;
            case About:
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToAbout" sender:sender];
                break;
            default:
                break;
```

Comment: What didn't work? Could you explain more?

Comment: I have two different segues inside the switchCase. So when the UIPickerView returns the value 0, it should switch to the "GameViewController" and when the returned value is 1, it should switch to the "OptionsViewController". But when I select the Options-Object inside the UIPickerView, it just goes to the "GameViewController" and not to the "OptionsViewController"...

Comment: Post your switch statement code. My guess is you're missing a `break;` in there

Comment: Switch statement looks good to me. I think the problem is either of: a) Start_Game == Options, make sure those have different values, b) rowSelected == Start_Game, again make sure that your picker view returns what you pick. I'd recommend putting a break point in your debugger and stepping this code through while paying attention to variable values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this...

```
-(IBAction)btnClickMethod:(id)sender
{
    NSString *identifier;
    switch(cases)

       case 0:
           identifier=@"abc";  //set this identifier as per your case and condition
           break;

       case 1:
           identifier=@"def"; //set this identifier as per your case and condition
           break;

       default
           identifier=@"ghi" //set this identifier as per your case and condition
           break;

     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:sender];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"abc"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"def"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
```

so on...depends on number of cases in switch